# What happens in HTTP response to a GET request without Content-Length or Transfer-encoding?

Tags: http, http-headers

If a response to a GET request doesn't have the Content-Length or Transfer-encoding: chunked field, what happens? How does the client know when the message ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 7230 section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) contains a nice checklist of conditions for finding the message body size. Essentially it says the answer depends on what the status code is. The relevant conditions being #1 and #7.

> "1.  Any response ... with a 1xx
> (Informational), 204 (No Content), or 304 (Not Modified) status
> code is always terminated by the first empty line after the
> header fields, regardless of the header fields present in the
> message, and thus cannot contain a message body."

> "7.  Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message
> body length, so the message body length is determined by the
> number of octets received prior to **the server closing the
> connection**."

Its also worth knowing that the message may continue after the end of the body portion. [RFC 7230 section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.4) defines a **Trailers** feature where the payload may be followed by a second set of mime headers. If those exist the message ends where they do.

Comment: It's worth noting that trailers are only for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` (Section 4.4 only describes the `Trailers` header; the actual method for transmitting the trailing data is defined in 4.1.2 Chunked Trailer Part). However, in that case point 7 above doesn't apply, and the length is instead determined by the chunked transfer encoding (point 3 in the same list).

Comment: No. Chunked encoding trailers are a different type of trailers which are embedded within each chunk and thus inside the body portion. The HTTP Trailers mechanism in section 4.4 are mime headers suffixing the entire message - outside the body portion and not relying on chunked encoding use.

Comment: oops, I meant "includes" not "are". Both chunked and non-chunked trailers are indicated using the header. non-chunked trailers can follow the body even if only content-length is used.

Comment: Do you have a reference? 4.4 says "When a message includes a message body encoded with the chunked transfer coding"

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification

> The length of a message body is determined by one of the following (in
> order of precedence):
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message body length, so the message body length is determined by the number of octets received prior to the server closing the connection.

The client needs to detect that the connection is closed.

Comment: Wrong specification; it has been obsoleted by RFC 7230, but otherwise correct.